Race Condition when using React Leaflet with Google Tiles
I'm using Next.js 14 with React Leaflet in a client component like so:
<>
  <MapContainer
        key={mapType}
        center={location}
        zoom={zoom}
        className="rounded-l-2xl"
      >
        <CustomGoogleLayer
          apiKey={process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_MAPS_API_KEY}
          type={mapType}
        />
  </MapContainer>
</>

The CustomGoogleLayer uses @googlemaps/js-api-loader and creates an instance of L.gridLayer.googleMutant. However, occasionally, my guess is the script runs before googleMutant is loaded, resulting in the error: TypeError: L.gridLayer.googleMutant is not a function
It occurs around 20% of the time, more so on slower connections. I tested this in the chrome network tab by setting the throttle option to slow 4G or 3G. It looks like its a race condition, where the script tries to use L.gridLayer.googleMutant before its loaded.
Custom Google Layer code:
import * as React from 'react'
import * as L from 'leaflet'
import {
  createLayerComponent,
  updateGridLayer,
  LeafletContextInterface,
  LayerProps,
} from '@react-leaflet/core'
import 'leaflet.gridlayer.googlemutant/dist/Leaflet.GoogleMutant'
import { Loader, LoaderOptions } from '@googlemaps/js-api-loader'

interface IGoogleMapsAddLayer {
  name: 'BicyclingLayer' | 'TrafficLayer' | 'TransitLayer'
  options?: any
}

interface IProps extends L.gridLayer.GoogleMutantOptions {
  zIndex?: number
  useGoogMapsLoader?: boolean
  googleMapsLoaderConf?: LoaderOptions
  googleMapsAddLayers?: IGoogleMapsAddLayer[]
  apiKey?: string
}

let googleMapsScriptLoaded = false

const createLeafletElement = (
  props: IProps,
  context: LeafletContextInterface
) => {
  const {
    apiKey = '',
    useGoogMapsLoader = true,
    googleMapsLoaderConf = {},
    googleMapsAddLayers,
    ...googleMutantProps
  } = props
  if (useGoogMapsLoader && !googleMapsScriptLoaded) {
    const loader = new Loader({ apiKey, ...googleMapsLoaderConf })
    loader.load()
    googleMapsScriptLoaded = true
  }
  const instance = L.gridLayer.googleMutant(googleMutantProps)
  if (googleMapsAddLayers) {
    googleMapsAddLayers.forEach((layer) => {
      ;(instance as L.gridLayer.GoogleMutant).addGoogleLayer(
        layer.name,
        layer.options
      )
    })
  }
  return { instance, context }
}

export default createLayerComponent<L.GridLayer, LayerProps & IProps>(
  createLeafletElement,
  updateGridLayer
)

I'm not sure how to fix this, but it results in a client side js error(TypeError: L.gridLayer.googleMutant is not a function) sometimes and the map doesn't load. After a few refreshes it fixes itself.
Unsure how to solve this and ensure that the googleMutant is added to gridLayer before the script runs, would appreciate any support!
